# Low-level encoding of pdf417 bardocde

Tags: python, lua, latex, barcode, pdf417

I am trying to generate a `pdf417` barcode in `LaTeX`. If I got it right, I can represent the code as a list of zeros and ones and then turn it into black and white boxes using LaTeX.

I am following this page http://grandzebu.net/informatique/codbar-en/pdf417.htm

I have a `python` code that generates the codewords (high-level encoding):

```
from pdf417 import encode
import sys

# Some data to encode
text = sys.argv[1]
cols = int(sys.argv[2])
sec_lev = int(sys.argv[3])

# Convert to code words
codewords = encode(text, columns=cols, security_level=sec_lev, encoding="utf-8")
```

You can do `print(codewords)` to see the array.

How can I convert it to 0s and 1s (low-level encoding)?

P.S. I know how to produce an `.svg` using this library and embed it into a `.pdf` file produced by `LaTeX`, but I want to make this work using `(Lua)LaTeX` similar to this answer https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/88610/100689

Comment: https://github.com/mosquito/pdf417/blob/12b730b40fb1387bebf785a7dce6ba78bfeaf26d/pdf417/rendering.py#L23 this is the part in the python lib where the conversion from `codewords` to binary takes place (they just consider the numbers in binary)

Comment: What I don't understand is what all this python stuff helps you. In the end you'll need to have this in lua to make a latex package.

Comment: @atticus I will use external python script to do the job of generating binary code. I am not going to turn this into a package, just for personal use. I am going to look at the link you provided, thank you.